# Download Many files and folders from SharePoint when on a mac

Tags: 2007, mac-os-x

I have a higher up user who is attempting to download a lot of files from SharePoint.

Unfortunately he is on a Mac computer so Windows explorer view is unavailable.

I have not been able to find anyway outside of downloading an application which is not an option.

What is the best way to download a large amount of files and folders onto your computer from SharePoint when using a Mac.

Comment: Make him upgrade to SP2013 ;)

Answer (score 0):

There're many ways we can do this on Windows : Sync with onedrive / open with explorer / map to network drive. Since explorer is not an option, I looked into the other 2 options. My google-fu lead me to this article: http://sharepoint.rackspace.com/Learning/Articles/Pages/SharePoint-2013--how-to-sync-files-on-a-mac.aspx. Maybe this will help.

Update : Noticed you are on 2007. Microsoft Document Connection mentioned in the above article seems to work with SP 2007 as well. See if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Mac pro, but you should be able to map a network drive to SharePoint. SharePoint serves it's folders up as WebDav and I *think* Mac should support that.